# ffmpeg - losslessly compress upscaled video

Tags: video, ffmpeg, compression, video-conversion, h.264

I cannot seem to find a good answer to this. I have a video file, h264, 1280x720, 251.2 MB.

However the video is upscaled, the actual quality is 1024x576. And not just the numbers are different, there actually are more pixels, I know this because I have the same video in that resolution, and it is around 70 MB, the quality is the same or arguably better. Can I compress the video using ffmpeg back to 576p and that same size, with no quality loss? In other words, can I get rid of the extra pixels without harming the good pixels?

The best result I've got so far is like this:
`ffmpeg -i video.mp4 -vcodec libx264 -crf 23 -acodec copy -vf "scale=1024:576" output.mp4`, but there is a slight quality loss. Can I do this completely losslessly?

edit: maybe my wording was unclear. Of course it can't magically know which pixels to get rid of, but that can be calculated, can't it? Say I have a 4x4 image, composed of 4 colors in a 2x2 grid. Now I can easily compress that to a 2x2 image and lose nothing at all, I can take pixels of the same color and group them into one, thus having less information. Can't that process be done for my upscaled video? (along with losslessly compressing every frame). I do not mind the output codec being different.

In a few words, I want to take every frame, downscale it by lowering the number of pixels (which does not result in any quality loss whatsoever because the video is upscaled), then compress the result to a lossless codec. Lossy to lossless shouldn't result in quality loss. I can't understand what's not possible about this.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111822/discussion-on-question-by-mikey-john-ffmpeg-losslessly-compress-upscaled-video).

Answer (score 4):

The short answer is no, you cannot do it completely losslessly.

When video is scaled, an upsampling filter is used which modifies *all* pixels.  There is no such thing as "good pixels" and "extra pixels".  If you knew which upsampling filter was used, in theory the inverse filter could be applied and exactly undo the upsampling.

In reality, you probably don't know which filter was used for upsampling, and most likely the filter you use for downsampling won't be the exact inverse.  Furthermore, encoding the upsampled video has introduced some distortion which will also be in the downsampled video.

But for the sake of argument, let's assume you've got downsampled video at the desired resolution which you're OK with.

The next step is to re-encode it.  You *could* do that losslessly with `ffmpeg` using `-crf 0`.  If you want something "like zip", then this is the answer.

However, the file that results will be large.  A traditional video codec achieves efficiency through lossy compression, and by demanding lossless you've prohibited it from using a large number of the techniques it would normally use.

If you want a smaller file, then you'll be operating in a "lossy" mode with some quantization/rate control.

That said, if your slightly upsampled file is significantly larger (in bytes) than the original, it suggests it was coded with a very low QP value, so you probably wouldn't lose much by going up and down.

Comment: copy-pasting comment from above:

but theoretically however it seems possible. Just make sure you display the same pixels on every frame, but store that information compressed, like a zip file? Also, would choosing a different output codec make a difference?

Comment: The loss is introduced through quantization/rate control which happens each time the video is re-encoded.  You cannot recover anything that was lost through the upsampling/re-encoding process - that is already gone.  If you want the maximum quality when downsampling, then you simply apply a very low QP value or use a lossless codec.

Comment: As I said, I don't mind the output codec being different. And I'm of course not asking to get better quality, I just want the same quality as the input but a smaller size, input is definitely uncompressed (or at least, not compressed enough), I want to compress it without losing anything, the same way you can compress something to a zip file.

Comment: @mikey_john zip is lossless compression, mp4 is not. So by definition you cannot compress it the same way as a zip file.

Comment: Understood. The best you can do with `ffmpeg` is `-crf 0`.  If that does not work for you (i.e. produces a file that is too large) then you will either need to code with a higher QP (and expect some loss), or you will need to consider a different compression method.  H.264 (and video codecs in general) do not work like zip.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke As I said, I do not mind the output being a different codec, I can accept any kind of output codec. It currently is h264, but it doesn't have to be reencoded back to h264.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke can anyone answer?

Comment: As said above, if you want to operate `ffmpeg` in lossless mode, then pass `-crf 0` (see https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Encode/H.264).

Comment: @mikey_john it has been answered, right? I.e. it is not possible as the input file is lossy and there's no way to determine the "original" pixels. [An mp4 is not a series of full frames](https://blog.video.ibm.com/streaming-video-tips/keyframes-interframe-video-compression/) which you can go to one by one and extract certain pixels, it's more complex than that. Somehow you still believe it must be possible, so perhaps you can do some web searches to see how others are doing this possible thing?

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke Read my question fully, I performed many edits. Regarding the scale, I only want to reduce the number of pixels, I'm not asking for any magic to determine what pixels to keep and what to get rid of, the video quality is 576p therefore just downscaling won't result in quality loss. My issue is the output file, I want to save it in a lossless codec (it does not matter what codec input is, you can decompress h264 the same way a player does) and compress it at the maximum.

Comment: @mikey_john I assume I've read it carefully. Did you read the [help section on how to ask a question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)? Especially the part about `Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question?`

Comment: If `-crf 0` doesn't work for you, then send it to JPEG2000 in lossless mode and enjoy an even larger file size.

Comment: @SaaruLindestøkke I did perform searches and I didn't find a good result. 

What I don't get is why should the size be bigger? If I decompress it it'll be, but can't I theoretically keep the same compression algorithm and not lose quality (if I encode to a lossless codec)? Size should be at least equal, no? And since I'm removing 20% of the pixels, shouldn't size be smaller? Can anyone explain why if not?